# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to implement optional validation using Fluent Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

I have this validator using Fluent Validation in ASP.NET Core-6 Web API :

```
public TransactionValidator()
{
    RuleFor(p => p.Token)
        .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure);
}
```

Token should either be null, or it has input value of exactly 6 lengths.

How do I get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fluent validation supports [predicate validator](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html?predicate-validator) via `Must`:

```
RuleFor(p => p.Token)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
    .Must(s => s == null || s.Length == 6);
```

Or the same can be achieved with [conditions](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/conditions.html#conditions):

```
RuleFor(p => p.Token)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
    .Length(6)
    .When(c => c.Token != null);
```